# Socksify and Ruby

Tags: ruby, post, get

I'm new to Ruby, but I need to make a little script, which will make POST requests to the server, with some parameters from the previous GET request. I found some template on the Internet and tried to change it for myself. But id didn't want to work. Here is my code:

```
require 'socksify/http'
useragents = File.readlines('useragents.txt')
uri = URI.parse('http://madrobots.ru/bf/')
TCPSocket::socks_server = "127.0.0.1"
TCPSocket::socks_port = 9050
rubyforge_www = TCPSocket.new("rubyforge.org", 80)


Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy('127.0.0.1', 9050).start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  useragent = useragents.sample
  # get
  headers_get = {
      'User-Agent' => useragent,
      'Referer' => uri
  }
  res = http.get(uri.path, headers_get)
  all_cookies = res.get_fields('set-cookie')
  cookies_array = Array.new
  all_cookies.each { | cookie |
    cookies_array.push(cookie.split('; ')[0])
  }
  cookies = cookies_array.join('; ')
  r = %r{'bitrix_sessid':'(\w+)'}.match res.body
  sessid = r && r[1] ? r[1] : ''
  # post
  data = "SOME_FIELD_1=Y&OTHER_FIELD_2=123&sessid=#{sessid.to_s}"
  headers_post = {
      'User-Agent' => useragent,
      'Referer' => uri,
      'Cookie' => cookies
  }
  res = http.post(uri.path, data, headers_post)
end
```

And this is what I get, when I try to start it:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/socksify-1.7.0/lib/socksify.rb:169:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9050 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/socksify-1.7.0/lib/socksify.rb:169:in `initialize'
from main.rb:6:in `new'
from main.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/socksify-1.7.0/bin/socksify_ruby:13:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/socksify-1.7.0/bin/socksify_ruby:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/socksify_ruby:22:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/socksify_ruby:22:in `<main>'
```

I'm starting it this way:

```
socksify_ruby localhost 9050 main.rb
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to bypass inexisting proxy, or your proxy server is not located on your machine and/or is not using 9050 port.